# Function to return data from SQLite3 query in node.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm making a bot for Discord, and one of the features in this bot is a level system. I've decided to go from using JSON to store the data, to sqlite. I'm using sqlite3 in node.js and am trying to create a function to create / retrieve a player's data. My goal is to make this function return the data from the query, but I'm running my head into a brick wall trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've read that I need to use callbacks sent to the query function, but that has not worked for me either (nor will it work for the goal of this function).

So any help on how I can create a function to return the data from the query would be extremely helpful! This is the code I have so far before I've given up and decided to come here for help before I lose any more hair. Everything else is working as I intend, I am just unable to retrieve the data from the db.each().

```
exports.getPlayerData = function(players,msg,mention = false){
if(mention){
    // console.log("mention found");
    var member = msg.mentions.users.first();
} else {
    var member = msg.member.user;
};
var db = new sqlite3.Database('data/levels/' + msg.guild.id + '.db');
var check;
db.serialize(function() {
    var stmt = "CREATE TABLE if not exists uid_" + member.id  + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT, avatarID TEXT, avatarURL TEXT, xp INTEGER, level INTEGER, lastXp INTEGER)";
    db.run(stmt);

    db.run("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO uid_" + member.id  + " (id,username,avatarURL,xp,level,lastXP) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)", member.id,member.username, member.avatarURL , 0, 0, 0);
    db.each("SELECT * FROM uid_" + member.id + " WHERE id = " + member.id , function(err, row) {
        console.log(row);
        return row;
    });

});
// return row;
db.close();
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, then you must be facing issue related to the placement of `return` statement. You want to return all rows, but aren't able to return, because of asynchronous nature of code.

I checked the documentation of `sqlite3`'s `.each`, and found out that there exist `complete` callback that you can call after you have fetched all rows. In that callback, you can return `data` array that has collection of rows.

**Update:** You have to use callback

```
exports.getPlayerData = function(players,msg,mention = false, callback){
    if(mention){
        // console.log("mention found");
        var member = msg.mentions.users.first();
    } else {
        var member = msg.member.user;
    };
    var db = new sqlite3.Database('data/levels/' + msg.guild.id + '.db');
    var data = []; //for storing the rows.
    db.serialize(function() {
        var stmt = "CREATE TABLE if not exists uid_" + member.id  + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT, avatarID TEXT, avatarURL TEXT, xp INTEGER, level INTEGER, lastXp INTEGER)";
        db.run(stmt);

        db.run("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO uid_" + member.id  + " (id,username,avatarURL,xp,level,lastXP) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)", member.id,member.username, member.avatarURL , 0, 0, 0);

        db.each("SELECT * FROM uid_" + member.id + " WHERE id = " + member.id , function(err, row) {
            data.push(row); //pushing rows into array
        }, function(){ // calling function when all rows have been pulled
            db.close(); //closing connection
            callback(data); 
        });
    });
}
```

To have to pass callback to get player data.

```
getPlayerData(players, msg, false, function(data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

Hope it works for you and saved your hair :). Let me know, if there are any issues.

Comment: I had tried something similar to this as well, unfortunately, still getting an undefined from this. Not exactly sure what the deal is here. Seems like this should be easier to do... Perhaps I should look into a different module than sqlite3?

Comment: I tried and ran above code. It worked fine. It didn't return undefined.

Comment: Doing the following:
var player = this.getPlayerData(players,msg,false);
console.log(player);

gives me undefined. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: i didn't check it in that way. For this way, you have to use callback. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I love how these problems almost always end up being the easiest fix,,, In my code I did try the callback on getPlayerData.I had getPlayerData(players, msg, false, function(){...}.

Which would explain my issue! Thanks again!

Comment: Great simple answer here - use .all - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106668/node-js-sqlite3-read-all-records-in-table-and-return

Answer (score 1):

You should go with wait.for npm.

More example can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait.for

Sharing code which worked for me below you can find it :

```
var wait = req.app.get('wait');
wait.launchFiber(handleGet, req, res);
function handleGet(req, res)
{   
    var slashes     =   req.app.get('slashes');
    var connection = req.app.get('connection');
    var user_lib = req.app.get('user_lib'); 
    var user_id = req.params.userId;    
    user_id = slashes.add(user_id);
    var user_insert_id = wait.for(user_lib.update_user_status, connection, user_id);
    res.render('view/email_verification', { req:req, res:res});
}
```

user code lib file :

```
Object.prototype.update_user_status=function (connection, cc_user_id, callback)
{
     connection.query('update cc_user set cc_user_active="yes" where cc_user_id ="'+cc_user_id+'"',function(err,rows){      
        if(err) throw err;          
        if(rows)
        {
            return callback(err,{rows:rows});
        }
    }); 
}
```