# Running node sqlite3 code synchronously

Tags: node.js, typescript, sqlite

I'm having trouble adjusting to the async-first nature of node / js / typescript. This intent of this little function should be pretty clear: it takes a database and returns an array of courses that are listed in that database.

The problem is that the return statement gets run before any of the database operations have run, and I get an empty list. When I set a breakpoint inside the database `each` loop, I can see that the rows are being found and that courses are being put into `ret` one by one, but these courses never become visible in the scope where `courseList()` was called.

```
const courseList = (database: sqlite3.Database): Course[] => {
    let ret = new Array<Course>();

    database.serialize();
    database.each("select ID, Title from Course", (err: Error, row: Object) => {
        ret.push(new Course(
            row.ID,
            row.Title
        ))
    })

    return ret;
}
```

Suggestions?

The calling code just wants to print information about courses. For example:

```
let courses = courseList(db);
console.log(courses.length); // logs 0, even though the db contains courses
```

Comment: Nothing special about NodeJS here, just higher order functions, specifically callbacks. Can you show the calling code?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106668/node-js-sqlite3-read-all-records-in-table-and-return

Comment: @AluanHaddad Added some example calling code.

Comment: @NiloCK you have a bug somewhere else or code you are omitting. The function indeed works. See here where I have your code but with a mocked database http://jsbin.com/rixivofeke/1/edit?js,console Yes, there is a race condition, but the function returns a value. It does not behave as you describe.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I think I muddled that. If you're VSCode handy, this repo: www.github.com/nilock/lynda-copy-course can be built / launched to demonstrate the behavior. See lines 9-12 of /bin/lynda-copy-course.ts, and lines 20-35, and 66-86 of /src/index.ts

Comment: But can you fix the question so that it indicates demonstrates the error? As it stands this question is confusing.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Fixed.

Comment: To be fair they do become visible, your program logs 0 and then 6.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, the question is how to see and operate on the 6 from the calling context. And it remains unclear to me whether the 6 are ever present as the member of the instantiated copier object.

Comment: Look at the Q/A that @orhankutlu linked, it holds the solution.

Answer (score 2):

`database.each` takes a complete callback. Use that to resume e.g.

```
const courseList = (database: sqlite3.Database, complete): Course[] => {
    let ret = new Array<Course>();

    database.serialize();
    database.each("select ID, Title from Course", (err: Error, row: Object) => {
        ret.push(new Course(
            row.ID,
            row.Title
        ))
    }, complete);

    return ret;
}
let courses = courseList(db, () => {
    console.log(courses.length); 
});
```

## More

- There are better ways to write this. Use promises https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/promise.html
- The documentation is horrible : https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki I would be tempted to look elsewhere (TS First) for a database solution. Its not worth the pain for me personally. YMMV.