# sqlite3, each, and async with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

so - we use sqlite3 heavily, and typically I use **all** to select - but we have a situation where we have a large dataset (tens of millions of rows) and I wanted to process it row by row... and ran into what seems like an insurmountable problem.

if I do

```js
console.log("before");
database.each( "select * from blah", 
    (error, row) => {console.log("during");output.write(row.something);} );
console.log("after");
```

I see the words "before", "after", "during".   Now the problem with this - I need to close the stream - *after* the last record has come out.   There seems to be no way to determine that point, or get a callback when that happens.

Am I missing something?  Almost every time someone iterates over what is basically a cursor, they will need a way to know when they've finished - and as far as I can tell - it's just completely impossible with the current javascript implementation, which makes the **.each** essentially unusable.

Please tell me I'm wrong?

Comment: ps - I know I could query the count beforehand, but there's a serious implicit race condition with that, as well as a performance cost.

Comment: It seems that you can pass also [completion callback](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete) as last parameter

Comment: Yay!   Thx will try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js - sqlite3 read all records in table and return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106668/node-js-sqlite3-read-all-records-in-table-and-return)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the completion callback in the db.each function like -

```
console.log("before");

database.each( "select * from blah", (error, row) => {
    console.log("during");
    output.write(row.something);
}, (err, count) {
    // close your stream here or use a promise and resolve it from here
    stream.close();
}));

console.log("after");
```